# SQL Server 2005 simple update statment with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables, one called `dbo.dd` and one called `dbo.gt.`

`where dbo.gt.v_products_model = dbo.dd.[Vendor Stock Code]`

I would like to update the

field `dbo.gt.v_products_price` with the `dbo.dd.[Dealer Ex]`

Sorry, forgot syntax of SQL 2005 and in a jam!

Comment: Books Online is a good resource!

Comment: Even Decepticons mark the most helpful, most correct answers as correct.  Was Barry's answer helpful?

Answer (score 3):

```
Update g
set g.v_product = d.[Dealer Ex]
From dbo.gt g 
Join dbo.dd d on g.v_products_model = d.[Vendor Stock Code]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to my day job!